# UICollectionView + UISearchController - How to achieve smooth scrolling animation when hiding search bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I notice that, normal implementation for `UICollectionView` + `UISearchController`, will not able to achieve smooth scrolling animation when hiding search bar.

As you can see in the below video, when we scroll upward the page, it seems like "the page has slipped up suddenly".

[image]

If we compare the animation with search bar in iOS Settings page, the problem is more obvious. iOS Settings page able to have a smooth scrolling experience.

[image]

---

### Implementation

The following is our implementation. The complete workable project is found at : https://github.com/yccheok/demo-uicollectionview-uisearchcontroller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    let reuseIdentifier = "cell" // also enter this string as the cell identifier in the storyboard
    var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "bye"]
    
    private lazy var searchController: UISearchController = {
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: UIViewController())
        
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "search_todos"
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

        return searchController
    }()
   
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }
    
    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol
    
    // tell the collection view how many cells to make
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }
    
    // make a cell for each cell index path
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        
        // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
        cell.label.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
        cell.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        return cell
    }
    
    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // handle tap events
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    }
}

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
}

extension ViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    }
}

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
}
```

Do you have any idea, how we can achieve such a smooth scrolling animation? Thanks.

Comment: Try using a UICollectionViewController instead of a UIViewController+UICollectionView. Also test on a real device. It's not uncommon for such animations to appear jumpy in a simulator.

Comment: Yes. Using `UICollectionViewController` is able to resolve such an issue. However, `UICollectionViewController` itself does have an edge case bug, when implementing reordering + context menu. Is it possible still get this work by using `UIViewController+UICollectionView`?